# WCF data serialization performance issue

Tags: performance, wcf, serialization

I have a WCF based client service application. I'm using EF to interact with mysql db. I'm using my own entities for data transferring between client and server. Here is my binding schema:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="...BusinessService" behaviorConfiguration="SimpleServiceBehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://127.0.0.1:8001/....BusinessService/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="CommonService" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTCPBindingCommon" contract="....ICommonService"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="NetTCPBindingCommon" closeTimeout="00:11:00" openTimeout="00:11:00" 
                receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" 
                maxBufferSize="65536000" maxBufferPoolSize="52428800" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536000" 
                hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" transferMode="Buffered" transactionFlow="false" 
                transactionProtocol="OleTransactions">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="81920000" maxArrayLength="16384000" 
                maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="1638400"/>
    </binding>
    .......
```

The data serialization and deserialization during client service data transfering is very slow. How can I make it more faster?
What is today's best solution for performance issue?
Is Json.NET the best solution as I found on some forums?

Comment: What do you  mean by transferring is very slow?  Slow compared to what?

Comment: Give some numbers. How many objects per second do you observe per CPU core?

Comment: How do you know the serialization is slow (as opposed to the network-transfer, or the actual service method)?  Have you tested `DataContractSerializer` separately on your request/response objects?  We will need more than your config file to really help with an issue like that.